# interchanging double summation with the upper limit of one summation being other's index

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let's say I have an infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{nk}$ which converge. Now I want to interchange the order of summation to sum $n$ first, so the series become $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_{nk}$. I would like to ask, can we do that without assuming the series absolute converge? If we use limit notation, the first series is $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{nk}$, if we change the order of summation, it becomes $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{n=k}^{N}a_{nk}$, there are no interchange of limit so it seems possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{n,k}:=\frac 1{k^2}-\frac 1{(k-1)^2}$ for $k\geq 2$ and $a_{n,1}:=1$ for all $n$.
We have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{+\infty} a_{n,k}
$$
diverges, as already the inner sum diverges.